# How do you order by a left join with graphql apollo federaton?

Tags: apollo, apollo-federation

I'm using apollo federation. I need to order owners by if they written a product review for a particular product, and then the ones that haven't last.

In psql world it's really simple

```
select * from owners o
left join reviews r on o.id = r.owner_id
order by r.id nulls last
```

The problem I'm running into is that owners and reviews belong to different microservices. And I'm not sure how to order the owners correctly on the backend.  It feels that owners would have to know about their reviews, but reviews exist in a different service.

The query I'm thinking of supporting looks like this

```
query {
  owners(productId: 5, paginationStuff) { 
     id
     firstName
     lastName
     reviews {
        id
        text
     }
  }
}
```

I could do query by reviews and associate the owners that way, but that wouldn't get all the owners. It also needs to support pagination, so I can't just return all owners and all reviews and have the client zip it up.